# where to place wsgi script in django project

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am learning django and just created a new project with *django-admin.py*, I am working on django1.6.

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) says:

> Note that you should not go placing the 'django.wsgi' file in the same directory as the 'settings.py' file, always use a subdirectory. This is because Apache is being configured to allow serving of files from that subdirectory. If you put it in the same directory as the 'settings.py' file, you would be inadvertantly allowing Apache to serve up your source code if someone accidentally mapped a URL to some parent directory of your project.

But when I created new project, the *django-admin.py* created *wsgi.py* file in the same directory in which the *settings.py* file lives. I am confused, is *wsgi.py* file the same wsgi script that is pointed out in the above quoted paragraph? OR should I manually move the *wsgi.py* file to a subdirectory?

If I am wrong here please guide me through the right way as I am new to django. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about django, but it seems to me that `django.wsgi` and `wsgi.py` have at least different names. And the section you quoted refers to the former one. Maybe the latter is a template or something.

Comment: @glglgl, before using django1.6 I tried 1.2 version of it, which did not create any wsgi.py file. In the documentation I read that I need to create a django.wsgi file myself and place it in the subdirectory of the directory where settings.py lives. But now when I am on 1.6 version, it automatically created wsgi.py. The contents in wsgi.py are same as in django.wsgi. So I think that in newer version of django they changed the name of wsgi file from django.wsgi to wsgi.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are supposed to create a new directory say *apache* and place your wsgi scrip in this directory. I don't know why settings.py and wsgi.py are created in the same place by default!

Answer (score 1):

Go read the documentation on the Django site:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

It is more up to date as to what to do for newer versions of Django.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named `apache` in your project directory and put `wsgi.py` file there. Then in apache configuration file add following line to point to that file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/apache/wsgi.py
# where /path/to/my/project/ is your project path
```